# Using spaces as delimiters in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I’m a bit new to ANTLR4 (and parsing in general), and I’m wondering if I’ve bitten off a little more than I can chew.

I’m trying to parse this line into a series of tokens:

```
This is some text @1 @2   @/searchstring/
```

Looks simple enough, but the problem is that I need to separate them into:

```
This is some text

@1
@2
@/searchstring/
```

I’ve come up with this for the grammar:

```
grammar Callout;

callout        : phrase parameterlist ;

phrase         : ~'@'+? ;

parameterlist  : param  (WHITESPACE+ param)* ;

param          : numericparam | searchparam ;

numericparam   : '@' DIGITS ;

DIGITS         : [0-9]+ ;

searchparam    : '@/' SEARCH '/' ;

SEARCH         : ~[/]+ ;

WHITESPACE     : [\t ] ;
```

I try it out and it seems to match the whole string without the `@` symbol (I imagine that’s because the longest match seems to be the whole string, though I’m not sure what happened to the `@` characters).

[image]

Comment: (1) When pasting pictures, show the whole UI of the browser, including the other panels, link, etc. (2) You did not clear the "lexer" grammar. Select the "lexer" tab, then erase all there. Then, rerun. (3) The rule `callout` is not EOF-terminated. So, it is not a valid start rule. It should be `callout: phrase parameterlist EOF;`. (4) `SEARCH : ~[/]+ ;` matches everything except '/'. The grammar cannot work. This is because Antlr lexer productions follow two rules: (a) always match the longest string first; (b) match the first production listed if two or more match.

Answer (score 0):

> and I’m wondering if I’ve bitten off a little more than I can chew.

Maybe. By looking at your grammar, I think it'd be good to start by learning/understanding the basics.

The part `~'@'+` in the rule `phrase : ~'@'+? ;` does not what you think it does. Using literal tokens (like `'@'`) inside parser rules will cause ANTLR to create tokens (lexer rules) for you. Your rule `phrase : ~'@'+?;` is translated into the following:

```
phrase
 : ~T__0+?
 ;

T__0
 : '@'
 ;
```

And the `~` inside a parser rule does not cause characters to be excluded, but tokens to be excluded. In other words: `~T__0` does not mean: "match any character other than an `@`", but rather: "match any token other than the `T__0` token". Best *not* use these literal tokens inside parser rules unless you know what you're doing (which you don't `;)`)

Also, ANTLR's lexer rules will consume as many characters as possible and the rule that matches the most, will "win". ANTLR will not try to match some other token if the parser is trying to match a certain token. So the rule `SEARCH : ~[/]+ ;` is too greedy: it will consume the input `This is some text @1 @2   @` into a single token.

Try something like this instead:

```
grammar Callout;

callout        : phrase parameterlist EOF;
phrase         : WORD+;
parameterlist  : param+;
param          : NUMERICPARAM | SEARCHPARAM ;

NUMERICPARAM   : '@' [0-9]+ ;
SEARCHPARAM    : '@/' WORD '/' ;
WORD           : ~[ @/]+ ;
WHITESPACE     : [\t ] -> skip;
```

Comment: Thanks to Bart and @kaby76 for the helpful answers. That gets me part of the way there. The problem is the phrase can also contain spaces, so I think I will have to use some kind of delimiter to separate it out from the parameters. But before I do any of that I clearly need to do a lot more background reading on parsing in general, and ANTLR in particular.